# Foreign key query laravel - the eloquent way

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to find a way to write eloquent way to query my model.

I have a `Form` model every form belongs to a `User` (Form:User = 1:1). Each `User` has a `State` and a `City` associated with them. `Admin` reviews a `Form` and each admin can be assigned to multiple `State` and `City`.

I want to find the `Form` that belongs to an `Admin`.

> This is the forms function in Admin.php (Model)

```
public function forms()
{  


        //cities
        $cities = $this->cities->pluck('name'); 
        //states
        $states = $this->states->pluck('name');


        //get all form from the user and states
        $forms = Form::whereHas('user',function ($query) use($cities,$states)
        {
          // find form from his states or cities
           $query->whereIn('state',$states)->orWhereIn('city',$cities);

        });
        return $forms;

}
```

Currently it returns all the forms. 
Any help will be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$citiesForms =$this->cities->forms->toArray();
$statesForms = $this->states->forms->toArray();

return array_merge($citiesForms, $statesForms);
```

and you can look for `hasManyThrough` to make this done in one line

Comment: `$this->cities->forms` would work if i have defined `form` relation in `City` model, even if i do, i'll have to write the same query there. Which again come back to this question!

Comment: you should make `hasManyThrough ` to get forms in city, based in users in that city.. see the [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)