# Laravel - get rows not in custom hasMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have an `admin` table and `admin` has many `form`. Each `form` is assigned to an `admin` that is displayed on their dashboard.

The trouble is there can be `form` that is that is not assigned to any `admin`.

I want to get all those `forms` Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Edit : `Admin` is related to `form` via a custom relation as described [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40945634/foreign-key-query-laravel-the-eloquent-way)

To summarize,

> Admin.php

```
public function states(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\State');
}

public function cities()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\City');
}

//gets the forms in  this admin's city or state
//Let me know if there is a better way to do this, i feel like im overdoing stuff here 
public function forms()
{  
        //cities
        $cities = $this->cities->pluck('name'); 
        //states
        $states = $this->states->pluck('name');

        $users =  User::whereIn('state',$states)>orWhereIn('city',$cities)->get()->pluck('id');

        $forms = Form::whereIn('user_id',$users);

        return $forms;

}
```

Id like to get the form that doesnt belong to any `admin`

Comment: You're basically going to have to define the inverse of that relationship on the forms model.

Comment: I have added the code, can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for [doesntHave](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence).

```
$forms=Form::doesntHave('admin')->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. Actually the relationship is not a standard has many relationship. I have edited the question to describe the situation better.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply do the reverse of it?

```
$forms = Form::whereNotIn('user_id', $users);
```